# How to disable default splash screen or how to reduce default splash screen duration?

Tags: android, native, android-splashscreen

How can I disable the default splash screen in Android 12 and above? I have used WindowIsTranslucent, but it is affecting the user experience. I also tried to customize it, but I can't disable it without affecting the user experience. So, how can we disable it, or can we reduce the splash screen duration?

I am expecting to disable default splash screen or i need to reduce the default splash screen duration.

Comment: can you share [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you are using in splash screen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is no separate activity for splash screen ,i am using default splash screen but i need to disable it.